# What is the bottom line on using Jakarta's JAXB (v3.0 or later) with OpenJDK 17?

Tags: xml, gradle, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I had stepped away from XML for quite some time, and am now trying to "step back in". The XML itself is not an issue (leastways, it all seems familiar to me), but the whole javax-to-jakarta is killing me, and every article I read seems to have a different solution (or, a different specific issue being resolved).

I am attempting to use OpenJDK 17, and trying to move forward with Jakarta's JAXB. I am managing my build using Gradle. All I want to accomplish is to marshall a POJO out as XML.

With that said, my current dependencies are declared as:

```
dependencies {
    // junit dependencies
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'

    // from https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri
    //   groupid:jakarta.xml.bind, artifactId:jakarta.xml.bind-api, version:4.0.0
    //   groupid:com.sun.xml.bind, artifactId:jaxb-impl, version:4.0.0
    implementation group: 'jakarta.xml.bind', name: 'jakarta.xml.bind-api', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '3.0.0'
}
```

A snippet of the marshaller class looks like (note: XmlMarker is simply an interface used to tag POJOs that should support marshalling to XML):

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class XmlMarshaller<T extends XmlMarker> {

    Class       pojoClazz   = null;
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
    Marshaller  marshaller  = null;

    public XmlMarshaller(T pojo) throws JAXBException {
        pojoClazz   = pojo.getClass();
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(pojoClazz);
        marshaller  = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    }
}
```

The code "builds" and "runs", but is returning a JAXBException with the message:
"2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions".

Specific questions I have are...

1 - What should be the included dependencies, if not what I currently have?

2 - Is Jakarta's JAXB implementation "really ready for primetime"? I have seen some advice to stick with javax as some third-party libraries have not yet migrated onto jakarta.

3 - I have also seen that Jakarta/Eclipse have published a v4.0.0. I am assuming this should be ready for primetime. Is there a reason not to jump onto v4.0.0 (vice v3.X)?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, "pilot error" appears to be the culprit.

In my POJO, I left out...

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

With that change, the answers to me questions appear to be:

1 - Those are the correct dependencies.

2 - Yes, Jakarta's JAXB is ready for primetime.

3 - Yes, 4.0 is also ready for primetime.

As an explanation, I got too caught up in the dependencies (i.e., assuming, based on prior issues with javax/jakarta namespaces) that these were the source of my problems), and overlooked the simple "check the generated error" approach.