# Migrating Spring Boot 2 to 3 throws org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Tags: spring-boot, jaxb

Started getting below exception(at runtime) after I migrated my code from Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3. Had to upgrade to using jakarta from javax during this process.

**Full stacktrace-**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:958) ~[spring-oxm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:519) ~[spring-oxm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:485) ~[spring-oxm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:83) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5 - cb19596]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:421) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5 - cb19596]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:255) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5 - cb19596]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1115) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5 - cb19596]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:144) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5 - cb19596]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:246) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5 - cb19596]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:58) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5 - cb19596]
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:322) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:392) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:349) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.createJaxbContextFromContextPath(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:542) ~[spring-oxm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:505) ~[spring-oxm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72607716/what-is-the-bottom-line-on-using-jakartas-jaxb-v3-0-or-later-with-openjdk-17) and [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/solved-exception-in-thread-main-com-sun-xml-internal-bind-v2-runtime-illegalannotationsexception-3-counts-of-illegalannotationexceptions/) might be helpful.